# Greatest lower bound of $\frac{(-1)^n}{4n}(n-8)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

> Find $\text{glb}(A)$ if $A = \left\{(-1)^n
> \left(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{2}{n}\right): n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$.

Let $x_n = \dfrac{(-1)^n(n-8)}{4n}.$ Clearly a lower bound for $x_n$ is $-\dfrac{3}{4}$. We want to show that $-\dfrac{3}{4}+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound for any $\epsilon > 0$. If $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an odd integer $2n+1$ such that $\dfrac{4n+10}{4(2n+1)}< \epsilon$. But then we have $x_{2n+1} = \dfrac{7-2n}{4(2n+1)}  = \dfrac{-3(2n+1)+4n+10}{4(2n+1)} = -\dfrac{3}{4}+\dfrac{4n+10}{4(2n+1)} < -\dfrac{3}{4}+\epsilon. $

Hence $-\dfrac{3}{4}+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound for $x_n$ for any $\epsilon > 0$. Hence $-\dfrac{3}{4}$ is the $\text{g.l.b.}$ i.e. $\text{glb}(A) = -\dfrac{3}{4}.$

Is this correct? Is it possible to do this in another way? If so, could someone please show me how?

Comment: "We want to show that $-\frac{3}{4}+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound for any $\epsilon > 0$." To show that, note that $x_2=-\frac34$, period. "If $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an odd integer $2n+1$ such that $\frac{4n+10}{4(2n+1)}< \epsilon$." Not true if $\epsilon\leqslant\frac12$.

Comment: @Did, Thanks. Why is it sufficient just to note that $x_2 = -\frac{3}{4}$? Regarding $ \epsilon \le \frac{1}{2}$, how would you fix that? In fact, I cannot construct a free $\epsilon$ after you have pointed that out!

Comment: @Did For $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an even integer $2n$ s.t. $\dfrac{2n-2}{2n}< \epsilon$. But then we have $$x_{2n} = \dfrac{2n-8}{4(2n)} = \dfrac{8(n-1)-6n}{4(2n)} = -\dfrac{3}{4}+\dfrac{2n-2}{2n}< -\dfrac{3}{4}+\epsilon. $$ I believe it works for all $\epsilon > 0 $ now. Thus $-\dfrac{3}{4}$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$.

Comment: Yeah, as I said, there exists an even integer $2n$ such that etc., simply *because this integer is $2n=2$*. In the end, $\inf S=x_2=-\frac34$ because $x_n\geqslant x_2$ for every $n\geqslant1$.

Comment: @Did Thank you, makes perfect sense that the said integer is all along the $2n = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it in another way using subsequences.

Let $x_{2k} = \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{2}{2k} = \dfrac{1}{4} - \dfrac{1}{k}$ be subsequence with even indexes, and let $x_{2k - 1} = -\dfrac{1}{4} + \dfrac{2}{2k + 1}$ be subsequence with odd indexes.

We know that $\dfrac{1}{k}$ is decreasing sequence, so we can tell right away that $x_{2k - 1}$ is decreasing subsequence, and $x_{2k}$ is increasing (you can check it if you're suspicious). Since $x_{2k}$ is increasing subsequence, and it's first element (for $k=1$) is $-\dfrac{3}{4}$, all other elements for $k \ge 2$ are greater than $-\dfrac{3}{4}$. We conclude that for even subsequence, $-\dfrac{3}{4}$ is glb or infimum since if we pick $k = -\dfrac{3}{4} + \epsilon, \epsilon \ge 0$, then $x_2$ will be less than $k$. Now only thing we need to check is odd subsequence $x_{2k - 1}$. It's not hard to see that $x_{2k - 1} > -\dfrac{1}{4} > -\dfrac{3}{4}$ for every k. So $-\dfrac{3}{4}$ is definitely a lower bound for $x_{2k - 1}$, and we showed that it is the glb or infimum for $x_{2k}$, so we can conclude that $-\dfrac{3}{4}$ is the infimum of $\{x_n\}$.

Comment: "we can conclude that $-\frac{3}{4}$ is the supremum of $\{x_n\}$.   " Can we? It is not, for example, $x_1=\frac74>-\frac34$.

Comment: i misused supremum instead of infimum. Thank you for pointing that out.